# String and non string data getting converted to 'null' for empty fields while exporting into Oracle table through hive

Tags: hadoop, hive, sqoop, impala

I am new to Hadoop and I have a scenario where I have to export the dataset/file from HDFS to Oracle table using sqoop export. The file has values of 'null' in it so same is getting exported in table as well. I want to know how we can replace 'null' with blank in database while exporting?

[image: File Structure- Sample record]

Answer (score 0):

In oracle empty strings and nulls are treated the same for varchars. That is why Oracle internally converts empty strings into nulls for `varchar`. When '' assigned to a char(1) it becomes ' ' (char types are blank padded strings).  See what Tom Kite says about this: https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0%3a%3a%3a%3aP11_QUESTION_ID:5984520277372

See this manual: https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/questions/empty_null.php

Comment: yes but here I am trying to export it from hadoop, & in Hadoop it's written as 'null' wherein it should be blank.

Comment: @Yogesh What will it give you it it were empty strings instead of nulls? In Oracle they will be written as nulls.

Comment: Is it possible to send blank instead of nulls? I am comparing the data loaded through Hadoop and from other system software that loads warehouse. Both needs to match. We are doing a proof of concept and data validations.

Comment: @Yogesh But in Oracle blank  will become null. And null != null. So, you need probably to use nvl(col, 'null') = nvl(col,'null') or  nvl(col,'x') when comparing. Or maybe I do not understand your scenario completely. Please add more workflow description

Comment: As I attached the pic of what is my data in HDFS, what I want is those character 'nulls' should come as blanks while exporting in Oracle. 'null' in Hadoop --> blank /empty in Oracle

Comment: @Yogesh But Oracle does not allow empty strings; they're silently converted to NULL for varchars. When '' assigned to a char(1) becomes ' ' (char types are blank padded strings). See updated answer please

Comment: @Yogesh So null or empty in Hadoop --> null or space padded char in Oracle.  zero length string is NULL in Oracle (it is no long '')

Answer (score 0):

You can create a TSV file from hive/beeline in that process you can add nulls to be blank with this `--nullemptystring=true`

Example : `beeline -u ${hhiveConnectionString} --outputformat=csv2 --showHeader=false --silent=true --nullemptystring=true --incremental=true -e 'set hive.support.quoted.identifiers =none; select * from someSchema.someTable where whatever > something' > /Your/Local/Location or EdgeNode/exportingfile.tsv`

You can use the created file in the sqoop export for exporting to Oracle table.

You can also replace the nulls with blanks on the file with Unix sed

Ex : `sed -i s/null//g /Your/file//Your/Local/Location or EdgeNode/exportingfile.tsv`

Comment: I did initial part of it working by adding --null-string '' --null-non-string '' in sqoop statement while importing the files at first place based on which converted dataset has to be drawn, But now I see few date columns has NULL in it where they are blank. Any idea how we can remove the NULL  in it? It used to be in small letters though before, 'null'!